# Using python to scrape a site (no form, session cookies)

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I'm trying to scrape a website for which I have a legitimate login.  When you try to visit this site, you get redirected to `Verify.aspx` until you enter a legitimate value for `access-code`.  Using  the `requests` library for Python, I have tried the following:

```
url1 = "<url>/Verify.aspx"
payload = {"access-code": "xxxxxxxx" }
ses = requests.Session()
r = requests.get(url1, data=payload)
```

When I then look at the value or `r.cookies`, I see that I've grabbed a bunch of cookies, stored in a cookie jar:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='ASP.NET_SessionId', value='...)]>
```

At this point, I'd like to retain the session information, and include it in future requests.  For example, below, I'd like to browse a normal page (i.e. `home`), so I try to visit the page, and I try to send the cookies along.

```
test = ses.post('<url>/home', cookies= r.cookies)
```

However, at this stage, when I look at the `test.text` in python, I can see from the code that I've just been redirected back to the original `Verify.aspx` page.

I've done a fair amount of googling with no success.  I have some familiarity with Python but none with scraping. I'd actually prefer and R solution since I'm better with it, but it seems to me that the Python scraping libraries are better than the R packages.  I don't want to use something like Selenium, unless it's via Python or R, since I want to pull and process data without any user interaction.

I feel stuck - I know that I'm passing a legitimate code, and am getting valid session cookies back since I can log in just fine via the normal webpage.  I just don't know how to capture, save and pass the session cookie information back to the page during the ensuing URL calls.

Everything I've read indicates to me that the `requests` library should handle everything about the cookies, but I think I'm just passing it incorrectly.

Can someone suggest what I might try next?

### #

EDIT
Thank you for looking, @Faboor.  I think I'm on a better track, since I now have a different error message.  Now when I look at the content of `print(test.text)`, it says "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.".  Is it OK that the second URL I try to access is not a discrete page (i.e. it seems like a folder, rather than something like index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you create a session, but not use it to login. Assuming that this is just a cookie manipulation issue, using `ses.get` and `ses.post` instead of `requests.get` should solve your problem.

```py
url1 = "<url>/Verify.aspx"
payload = {"access-code": "xxxxxxxx" }
ses = requests.Session()
r = ses.get(url1, data=payload)
test = ses.post('<url>/home')
```

You can check out what cookies are stored with the session using `ses.cookies`. Or for better readability (although losing some information about cookie origins) you can use `dict(ses.cookies)`

For more information about requests sessions, [check out the advanced usage docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)